# EF ComplexType column name (ModelFirst)

Tags: entity-framework, complextype, ef-model-first

I'm working on a EF 6 project (ModelFirst).

I use a complex type named "UserInfo" in all my tables.

But, when I create my database from my model, columns are prefixed by the name of the complex type ( ex: UserInfo_CreationDate)

Is there a way to define in the model the column name without its prefix (CreationData in place of UserInfo_CreationDate)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Annotations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/data/jj591583#TableColumn) or the [**FluentApi**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/data/jj591617.aspx#1.7).

For `FluentApi`, override the `OnModelCreating` method in your `dbContext` class 
and, for each property of class `UserInfo`, add a `HasColumnName` definition like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(s => s.UserInfo.CreationDate).HasColumnName("CreationData");  
}
```

For `Annotations`, in each property of class `UserInfo`, add an annotation like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    .....

    [Column("CreationDate")]
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}

    .....
}
```